# Как генерировать не только большие буквы но и маленькие

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал простой код, который генерирует рандомные буквы, но он генерирует их большими:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase
  
aa = random.randint(8,30)
a = (''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(aa)))

print (a)
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы гененрировались большие буквы, маленькие буквы
и цифры? Все они должны быть записанны в переменную "a" и должны идти в случайном порядке, чтобі рандомайзер мог сгенерировать число например: *jEjk34FOp442Gi*

Comment: Запишите в одну строку большой алфавит, маленький, и цифры, а потом выберите случайный индексы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase

random_uppercase = choice(ascii_uppercase)
random_lowercase = choice(ascii_lowercase)
random_digit = choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Если нужно сгенерировать что-то похожее на пароль из маленьких, больших букв и цифр, сделайте список допустимых символов и выбирайте из него:

```
from random import choice
        
symbols = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
password = (''.join(choice(symbols) for _ in range(12)))
        
>>> print(password)
VpJO2rnNZGjj
```

Comment: В таком случае будет генерироваться 3 разные переменные, и даже если воссоеденить их в один то они будут идти по порядку, "БОЛЬШИЕМЕЛКИЕ7" это уже не очень похоже на рандомайзер, нужно чтоб было случайное число мелких букв, случайное число больших букв, случайное число цыфр и все они были разбросанны случайным образомм в одну переменную

Comment: @Selasi дополнил ответ

Comment: небольшая поправочка, переменной pass не может быть, вить pass являеться методом

Comment: @Selasi согласен, поспешил... спасибо! исправил

Answer (score 2):

Вот самый простой пример

```
import random
chars = '1234567890abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

number = input('количество паролей?'+ "\n")
length = input('длина пароля?'+ "\n")
number = int(number)
length = int(length)


for n in range(number):
    password =''
    for i in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)
    print(password)
```

Comment: Давно не видел на ruSO простого человеческого кода